# How can I create a cancel button within a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to have a textBox and a cancel button/cancel image overlapped on the right side of it and which is supposed to clear the textBox data on it's click event. How can I implement it?

Comment: cancel button within a text box ? What do you mean by that & what it is for ?

Comment: do you mean a search textbox with having search button in it?

Comment: @Aswini: something like that... Cancel instead of search is what i need!!

Comment: what I need is a textBox and a cancel button/cancel image overlapped on the right side of it and which is supposed to clear the textBox data on it's click event

Answer (score 0):

You can have an image relative positioned on your textbox, handle the click event of that image in jquery or javascript to clear the text of the textbox.